# PHP & MySQL to get select values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running the following to get the type id and name from my MySQL database. Two results should be displayed. There are two options that show in the select list but there id or name is not present they are just shown as blank on the page.

```
function get_category_selector($form_name) {
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']['cur_category'])) {
    $curr = $_SESSION['loggedin']['cur_category'];
} else {
    $curr = -1;
}
$rtn = "";
$rtn .= '<select id="category" name="category">';
$rtn .= '<option value="-1"';
if ($curr == -1) {
    $rtn .= ' selected';
}
$rtn .= '>Select a Category</option>';
$DB = new mysql_db();
$DB->sql_connect();
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT (categories.categories_id), categories.categories_name FROM categories LEFT JOIN prod2cat ON prod2cat.prod2cat_cat = categories.categories_id LEFT JOIN products ON prod2cat.prod2cat_product = products.products_id LEFT JOIN prod2type ON products_id = prod2_product LEFT JOIN type ON prod2_type = type_id WHERE type.type_id =2 order by categories.categories_name asc";
$DB->query($q);
if ($DB->get_num_rows()) {
    $results = $DB->fetch_all_rows(MYSQL_ASSOC, NULL);
    foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
        $rtn .= '<option value="' . $row['Categories_ID'] . '"';
        if ($curr == $row['Categories_ID']) {
            $rtn .= ' selected';
        }
        $rtn .= '>' . trim($row['Categories_Name']) . '</option>';
    }
}
$rtn .= '</select>';

return $rtn;
```

}

Comment: Change to lowercase `$row['categories_id']` && `$row['categories_name']`

Comment: What is the mysql_db class?  Please point us  to how this works (post the class definition), thanks. ~Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the same case for you column names when accessing your result array:

```
$rtn .= '<option value="' . $row['categories_id'] . '"';
if ($curr == $row['categories_id']) {
   $rtn .= ' selected';
}
$rtn .= '>' . trim($row['categories_name']) . '</option>';
```

or you could change your select query:

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT (categories.categories_id) Categories_ID,
      categories.categories_name Categories_Name;
```